# wordpress plugin function firing twice

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Followed through on [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/display-woocommerce-categories-subcategories-and-products-in-separate-lists--cms-25479) post for manipulating `woocommerce` menu.
This plugin code:

```
function product_subcategories( $args = array() ) {
    $parentid = get_queried_object_id();

    $args = array(
        'parent' => $parentid
    );

    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

    if ( $terms ) {

        echo '<ul class="product-cats">';

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                echo '<li class="category">';                 

                    woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $term );

                    echo '<h2>';
                        echo '<a href="' .  esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
                            echo $term->name;
                        echo '</a>';
                    echo '</h2>';

                echo '</li>';


        }

        echo '</ul>';

    }     
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'product_subcategories', 50 );
```

Fires twice.

Why is that??
Thanx

EDIT
Original post link: [Display WooCommerce Categories, Subcategories, and Products in Separate Lists](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/display-woocommerce-categories-subcategories-and-products-in-separate-lists--cms-25479)
[image: Query Monitor woocommerce_before_shop_loop]

Comment: Are you tried to debug with Query Monitor plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Comment: AFA Query Monitor plugin goes please see EDIT of original question with screenshot... a single query for `tutsplus_product_subcategories()`

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce does allow you to register two events with the same tag [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/#source). Thus, if the file is loaded twice (e.g. if you use include/require instead of include_once/require_once) it can cause this problem: check it anyhow(!).

The hook itself is called twice in [woocommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_before_shop_loop), so technically it is possible that the hook is called twice. I do however not know if both templates are loaded in the same call... You might however have registered the call twice w/o knowing: thus check your code for another call to this function, perhaps with a different tag (other than `woocommerce_before_shop_loop`).

Comment: this is the only call for this plugin action as this is the only `php` code for it...there's nothing more besides `css`

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

With your code you are just doing what WooCommerce is already doing, that's why you are seeing duplicated category/subcategory menu items and you say that it's "fired twice".

Anyway, if you keep your code, and then you want to remove that WooCommerce generated category/subcategory items, you can use this hooked function:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_subcategories_args', function( $args ){
    $args['taxonomy']= '';
    return $args;
});
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> This will remove the WooCommerce duplicated items…

---

**Original answer:**

The [**`woocommerce_before_shop_loop`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_before_shop_loop) hook:

- has no arguments (no need to add **`$args = array()`** )
- is called many times, **but only fired once**. Check it replacing your code by this:

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', function(){
    wc_print_notice('test message', 'notice');
}, 50 );
```

Kindly, as your question is not very explicit and detailed, we don't really know what is your problem and can't help you further than that…

Comment: noted...removed `$args`....the `notice` function only shows up once...tried `has_action` & `did_action` but got nothing...as for the question, I did not want to overload with the code but the link says it all...it would help if you could please take a look...thank you for your time

Comment: P.s. `if (has_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'tutsplus_product_subcategories')) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'tutsplus_product_subcategories', 50 );
}` does not fire the function at all but if I negate the condition it does....where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Jadeye I have updated my answer… Please take a look to it. Thanks

Comment: I put it before `add_action` in the `plugin code`, in `functions.php`...did not work...sorry

Comment: @jadeye … This code is tested and perfectly works… you just put it at the end in your active theme function.php (but only the new filter in my update).

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answers are no doubt accurate, I don't think they are truly the reason for multiple calls. I believe the true reason is that you're simply receiving multiple HTTP requests when, to your eyes, it seems like there should only be one. Remember, your plugin is going to load upon every interaction with WP, not just the ones for your application. So /wp-cron.php links, for example, will trigger your plugin "invisibly", as will many other requests like Ajax or JSON calls. Please see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170768/wordpress-plugin-executing-code-twice#answer-170784.